# Node.js : Express app.get with multiple query parameters

Tags: node.js, express, get, query-string

I want to query the yelp api, and have the following route:

```
app.get("/yelp/term/:term/location/:location", yelp.listPlaces)
```

When I make a GET request to

`http://localhost:3000/yelp?term=food&location=austin`,

I get the error

```
Cannot GET /yelp?term=food&amp;location=austin
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the requested url `http://localhost:3000/yelp?term=food&location=austin`

- base url/address is `localhost:3000`
- route used for matching is `/yelp`
- querystring url-encoded data is `?term=food&location=austin` i.e. data is everything after ?

Query strings are not considered when peforming these matches, for example "GET /" would match the following route, as would "GET /?name=tobi".

So you should either :

- use app.get("/yelp") and extract the term and location from req.query like `req.query.term`
- use app.get("/yelp/term/:term/location/:location") but modify the url accordingly as luto described.

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried calling it like this?

```
http://localhost:30000/yelp/term/food/location/austin
```

The URL you need to call usually looks pretty much like the route, you could also change it to:

```
/yelp/:location/:term
```

To make it a little prettier:

```
http://localhost:30000/yelp/austin/food
```

Answer (score 4):

I want to add to @luto's answer. There is no need to define query string parameters in the route. For instance the route `/a` will handle the request for `/a?q=value`.

The url parameters is a shortcut to define all the matches for a pattern of route so the route `/a/:b` will match

1. `/a/b`
2. `/a/c`
3. `/a/anything`

it wont match

`/a/b/something` or `/a`

Answer (score 0):

Express 4.18.1 update:

using `app.get("/yelp/term/:term/location/:location")`, your query string can be `yelp/term/food/location/austin`

So your request url will look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/yelp/term/food/location/austin
```