# Multiple GET parameter with Express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm new to Node.js and Express, 
I've been working on a RESTful API project, and I'm trying to send a GET request with multiple parameters in the URL:

Here is my route:

```
/centers/:longitude/:latitude
```

and here is how I tried to call it:

```
/centers?logitude=23.08&latitude=12.12
```

and I also tried

```
/centers/23.08/12.12
```

It ends up going to this route:

```
/centers/
```

So is my way of writing the endpoint wrong? or the way I'm requesting it?

Comment: Post your code of how you are calling and how you are receiving.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js : Express app.get with multiple query parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020012/node-js-express-app-get-with-multiple-query-parameters)

Answer (score 13):

You are not correctly understanding how route definitions work in Express.

A route definition like this:

```
/centers/:longitude/:latitude
```

means that it is expecting a URL like this:

```
/centers/23.08/12.12
```

---

When you form a URL like this:

```
/centers?longitude=23.08&latitude=12.12
```

You are using query parameters (`param=value` pairs after the `?`).  To access those, see this question/answers: [How to access the GET parameters after "?" in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007997/how-to-access-the-get-parameters-after-in-express)

For that, you could create a route for `"/centers"` and then you would access `req.query.longitude` and `req.query.latitude` to access those particular query parameters.

Answer (score 6):

try like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.get('/centers/:log/:lat',function(req,res)
       {
res.json({ log: req.params.log,
          lat: req.params.lat });

});
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);
```

now try url like this http://localhost:8080/centers/55/55

[image]

Comment: How can I do this in single route? =  /v2/search/:query&:author

Answer (score 1):

It`s easier to define url parameters in router .

> Example url : http://www.example.com/api/users/3&0

in routes.js

```
router.get('/api/users/:id&:pending', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.id);
  console.log(req.params.pending);
});
```