# Using GET with Node.js

Tags: node.js, get

I want to use GET, to get the value of a variable, inside a node.js page I made, as I would normally do (with $_GET) using PHP.

Here is how it looks:

```
http://mygreatpage.herokuapp.com/myThing?X=57
```

The question is:

**How do I get the value of X (57 in the example above) inside my index.js file?**

Comment: Please read https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html

Comment: Show us the code for your node.js server.  Are you using Express or a plain http server?

Comment: OK, then I need to dig into that. But that seems incredibly complicated when in PHP I only need to write $x=$_GET['X']; to obtain what I need.

Comment: To jfriend100. I have no code to show since I don't know what to write. In PHP it would be: $x=$_GET['X'];

Comment: I have an index.js file working. And inside it, I want to catch the value of the parameter X. That's all.

Comment: @Michel dear did this work for u? or u need some thing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
app.get('/myThing',function(req,res)
console.log(req.query.X);
    res.send(req.query.X);
}
      );
app.listen(3000);
console.log("server start");
```

[image]

[check this for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007997/how-to-access-the-get-parameters-after-in-express)

[check this for multiple param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967927/multiple-get-parameter-with-express/40968503#40968503)